# Suspended sentence in Sharia law

Tags: sharia

I know that Sharia law allows forgiveness or compensation or full penalty but is there also something comparable to a suspended sentence in classical Sharia law?

Comment: For which sort of crime are you asking? Note that Huddud such as adultery, drinking, theft, robbery etc. can not be forgiven nor suspended when the case reaches the judge rather it is obligatory to enforce the prescribed punishment.

Comment: I was actually asking for any kind knowing that there are differences